# How can i work on Wordpress project from Docker container, without using bin/sh, with my IDE?

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, yaml

I was wondering if there is a way to like to speed up the workflow of installing and working on WP, without download install and configure WP each time.

I'm studying Docker, and i would like to know if is it possible, create a dockerfile that does:

1)install WP and mySQL

2)THEN in some way get the files "installed" in that container available to work on it, with my IDE!

Maybe some sort of reverse volume bind??

Hope everything is clear enough!

Thanks to everyone in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

This docker-compose can do the job

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb
    volumes:
      - gwordpress:/var/www/html

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb
      MYSQL_USER: exampleuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
    volumes:
      - gdb:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  gwordpress:
  gdb:
```

to start the applications, run

```
docker-compose up -d
```

and the app will be available at `http://127.0.0.1:8080`

You still need to install it for the first time, if you want to avid the first time installation you need to switch to custom docker images.

to share the files with your IDE, just change the volume `gwordpress` with a local path in your machine

Comment: Thank you for your answer:), however the installation process is the point that i would like to avoid, in some way.

Comment: then use custom Docker images